# Principal class parameter in main.m of iOs

Tags: objective-c

In the code below, nil says there is no principal class (nil class but not other real class) and the program creates an instance of AppDelegate class only? (accordingly to the UIApplicationMain definition)...

**Are there situations where we will use instead of nil here some real class name** (i.e. what for we need here this principal class parameter?) ?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: "the program creates an instance of AppDelegate class only" - no, it creates a singleton `UIApplication` instance as well. I haven't yet had the need to subclass `UIApplication` - the `AppDelegate` class has always sufficed for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you need to have a custom subclass of `UIApplication` be the shared application then you would pass your subclass there. I don't know what circumstances that would be - although the docs mention custom event dispatching.

Comment: Carl is correct, custom event dispatching is one reason you would want to do this.  I used this technique once to hide a view if it was visible for any touch event that happened in the app, without interfering with the behavior of the touch.  You must be very careful when you do such things, because adding any negative performance impact to event dispatch can be very costly.

Comment: Good to know about a possible usage - even if it seems to be a "hacky" solution.

Comment: @CharlesA. ah, that's a clever idea!

Comment: It's not really hacky, it's really the only way to insert anything custom into event dispatch at a high level.  This was prior to the existence of official support for container view controllers, mind you.  If I were to do it today I would have a top level container view controller that had a gesture recognizer attached to its root view.  Having said that, there are probably other rare uses for needing to interact with event dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

You would pass a class name there in case you want a custom UIApplication subclass. That's not a common practice in iOS as you use your app delegate to deal with any app level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a case when I was working on a React Native app that had predefined how the delegate class should look like and what it should extend. In our case, we needed to fire events to the JavaScript side when some touch gestures started/ended. I tried to implement that logic in the delegate class but encountered problems with that class not reporting all touches correctly when some modals or keyboard were shown in the screen. In this case I've used custom principal class that extended UIApplication in order to override the sendEvent method on it and correctly react to all touches.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).